# Minimum sizes for integral types

Tags: c++

Suppose I want to write a *minimum standard compiler* and I've reached the point where I need to implement the integral types. Am I correct in assuming that I can minimise the sizes of the integral types according to this table?

`char`: standard mandates `sizeof(char)` is always 1. Therefore 1 byte.

`short`: must be at least 2 bytes in. Therefore 2 bytes.

`int`: must be no smaller than `short`. Therefore 2 bytes.

`long`: must be no smaller than `int`. Therefore 2 bytes.

`long long`: must be longer than `long`. Therefore 17 bits (i.e. -65536 to +65535) if I implement twos compliment: I *think* that's a choice I can make).

`bool`: standard doesn't specify the size. Therefore 1 bit.

I'm aware I don't need to support `std::int64_t` and its unsigned cousin. Do I need to support `std::int32_t` or is that compiler discretion?

Comment: +1 - hell indeed - I know but it's more than childish curiousity: I'm building a serialiser so could do with knowing the lower bounds however theoretical.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types - you're off quite a bit on the requirements (linked page is for C, but applies to C++).

Comment: Do you mind if I edit the question? Nobody has answered yet so I guess it doesn't invalidate anything.

Comment: @mat: your link helps. I'll delete the question unless you want to put as an answer.

Comment: -1, Can't believe you don't know your data type sizes yet. Read a book this weekend ;-)

Comment: I took my source from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx

Comment: Read this one: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/, remember size of data type depends on your platform and your climits available on your platform's compiler suite

Comment: @SlodgeMonster: If you want to build a *standard* compiler, use the *standard* for reference. For the love of {insert supreme being of choice}, **do not** rely on MS for reference on *anything* (other than MS API's, and perhaps not even that)... That is not MS hate, that's years of experience with MS' cavalier way of handling (a.k.a., *ignoring*) standards.

Comment: nothing prevents you from making all types just 1 byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**The actual size of integer types varies by implementation.** The standard only requires size relations between the data types and minimum sizes for each data type:

The relation requirements are that the `long long` is not smaller than `long`, which is not smaller than `int`, which is not smaller than `short`. As `char`'s size is always the minimum supported data type, all other data types can't be smaller.

The minimum size for `char` is 8 bits, the minimum size for `short` and `int` is 16 bits, for `long` it is 32 bits and `long long` must contain at least 64 bits.

---

To obtain the max/min number for each type you can call:

```
#include <limits>
const int min_int = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
const int max_int = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

or C solution:

```
#include <limits.h>
const int min_int = INT_MIN;
const int max_int = INT_MAX;
```